# Why do I get symbol executions outside of the scope of my threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, profiling, rust-cargo, flamegraph

For learning purposes I was making a custom threadpool which happens to be performing slowly atm. I profile the code with `cargo flamegraph` and I am having a hard time understanding something in the output, it shows me this:

[image]
https://svgshare.com/i/13fs.svg

Notice how there are 3 symbols `[[heap]]` `[[anon]]` `[[unkown]]` that are taking 60% of the runtime.

I am compiling with debug symbols on:

```ini
[profile.release-with-debug]
inherits = "release"
debug = true
```

So first, I don't understand why I am getting three symbols that are effectively nameless.

The other thing I don't understand is why they appear outside the scope of `thread_start`? A large number of the symbols found under the 3 nameless ones are actually spawned by the threadpool work, so I don;t quite understand why they are showing up as if they belonged to a different scope?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman No, because in order to get a behaviour like this I would need to make a code that is far longer than the allowed SO limits.

I also just want to understand the flamegraph output. Not the code that generated it.

Comment: Even linking to a repository will be better than the current status. I don't know what this is, but having the ability to run the code myself may help me investigate.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman this is a link to the example in the repo causing the issue:
https://gitlab.com/Makogan/neverengine/-/tree/master/examples/07_fluid_mt?ref_type=heads

It should be enough to call cargo flamegraph, wait for the simulation to run for a bit and then close, wait for the svg file